# opening a file in the browser instead of downloading it

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, download, ssrs-2008

Im using ssrs through a reports server to generate a resultStream byte array using ReportExecutionService.Render() which I am currently serving to the user with the following code. **Is there a way I can use this same byte array to automatically open the report in a new browser window instead of going to the save/open dialog?**

```
   public void RenderReport (byte[] reportDigits, ReportItem reportItem)
   {
      HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
      response.Clear();
      response.ContentType = reportItem.ReportMimeType;
      response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", reportItem.ExportName));
      response.OutputStream.Write(reportDigits, 0, reportDigits.Length);
      response.End();
   }
```

In the past I have used a separate ReportViewer.aspx page that I would open first then display the report but would like to do it all in code behind if that is possible.

*Thanks*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this line:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", reportItem.ExportName));
```

Thats causing it to be downloaded. Comment out that line, and as long as the browser can handle the mime type, it will render in the browser window.

Comment: I dont want to takeover anyones page who's tryin to launch a report

Comment: javascript - `window.open('url_to_your_report.ext');` - you cant open a new window with server-side code

Comment: so save off the file and register the redirect script to it? thats no fun.

Comment: Oh right, that mean there is no real way to keep the filename and force to open in the browser. I have some images with an id in url but no extension. If the person want to save as, it use the id as filename... if I set the filename it tries to save directly.. It's just a pain in the ... when you just want to see if images resize correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the Header that you are adding to something other than an attachement.  Make it the format of your data--and hopefully the browser will recognize it.